# What code should I use?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image inside a Div and I would like it to change to another image on a simple click of the mouse, could someone please help me on if this can be done through CSS or would Jquery be the best way to go, here is the code :

```
    <div id="slideshow">    
<img class="one" src="img/TextSlide1.jpg" alt="Slide" id="slideShow" />
</div>
```

I have two other images named TextSlide2.jpg and TextSlide 3.jpg

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not enough effort in your question, so I will put basic answer. This is how to change image on click. you can loop through an array of sources and show next/previous. but effort is relative.

```
 <div id="slideshow">    
    <img class="one" src="img/TextSlide1.jpg" alt="Slide" id="slideShow" />
</div>

$('#slideshow img').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'nextImage.png');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/bwZ54/1/

Comment: Great thank you, that has worked.

Comment: HELP , I cant work out how to do this with three images and cant find anything online, please help me someone.